# LWC not loading in Production but works fine in sandbox

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am having an issue with my LWC where it works fine in sandbox but in production it does not load.

I have implemented it using lightning out on a vf page. In production, the vf page loads and gets the url parameters but the component does not load.

An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 680002303-76455 (1427019408)

This is the vf page. The paymentID and accID are shown in the console but the page remains blank and

console.log("LWC Component added in VF page"); doesn't get executed.

Any thoughts on this?

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" readOnly="false">
  <apex:includeLightning />
  <div id="LightningComponentid" />
  <script>
    var paymentID = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}";
    var accID = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.aid}";
    console.log("Payment ID " + paymentID);
    console.log("Received account ID : " + accID);
    $Lightning.use("c:ApplyPaymentsLWCApp", function () {
      $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:applyPaymentsLWC",
        { recordId: paymentID, accountId: accID },
        "LightningComponentid",
        function (cmp) {
          console.log("LWC Component added in VF page");
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks!

The two environments outputs..

[image: sandbox]

[image: Productioin]

Comment: Best to contact Support or someone that can look at the internal logs. There's no obvious inherent reason why this would work in one org but not another.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox